# TextBox Highlighted Text Visual Basic

Tags: vba, textbox

I have a problem with my TextBox. I'm trying to make a small program like memo. When you write something in the textbox it saves it for next time for you to open it again. But the problem is when you open the program once again, the old text is highlighted. So how I remove that?

```vb
   Public Class Form1 
     Private Sub 
       Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
       My.Settings.memo = TextBox1.Text My.Settings.Save() 
     End Sub 
     Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
       TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.memo + Environment.NewLine 
     End Sub 
   End Class
```

Comment: Can you include some source code?

Comment: Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        My.Settings.memo = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.memo + Environment.NewLine


    End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0):

See the TextBox.SelectionStart property